# Не выполняется php-код из примера

Tags: php

Я начал изучать производство сайтов, и первый же пример из книжки не хочет выполняться.

Я пишу:

```
<?php
    echo " Today is " . date("l") . ". ";
?>
Here's the latest news.
```

В CodeLobster не работает. Там надо ещё было указать путь файла php.ini, причём он вроде бы должен быть в папке проекта. Я только его скопировал. Может, скопировать всю остальную папку?

Comment: Код рабочий - проверить можно, например, тут: http://phptester.net/

Если CodeLobster сложен для вас - используйте OpenServer, там ничего никуда не надо копировать.

Answer (score 1):

В коде ошибок нет, проблема в вашей IDE.

Если вы работаете с Windows то скачайте [Openserver](https://ospanel.io/) и советую использовать другую IDE к примеру [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) или [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/)

Comment: Еще лучше, чтобы не возникали лишние проблемы, использовать Notepad++ или Atom безо всякого IDE :)

Comment: Atom не сказал бы, как по мне Sublime самый удобный и быстрый, если бы несколько возможностей в него добавить с PHPStorm сидел бы только в нём.

Comment: На начальном уровне лучше порой иметь меньше возможностей :) Кроме того, PHPStorm, если брать его легально, стоит $ 199.00 в год. Sublime, если подходить к нему по-честному, стоит $70. Для начала все же лучше использовать полностью бесплатные решения. А к Atom на выбор прилагается почти 6000 пакетов, что дает интересные возможности по его настройке.